# Bash end loop for postfix logs

Tags: bash, postfix-mta

bash script that search the postfix queue  id and search different .gz files in selected data range files , but script keeps on searching all logs if i gave same date  ,

wanted to search only selected date range files 
log files list in folder

```
maillog-02052020.log.gz
maillog-03052020.log.gz
maillog-04052020.log.gz
maillog-05052020.log.gz
maillog-06052020.log.gz
maillog-07052020.log.gz
maillog-08052020.log.gz
maillog-09052020.log.gz
```

executing this script like this

```
sh testscript.sh frommail@xyz.com  tomail@xyz.com  04/05/2020 06/05/2020
   script         from email id     to email id    from date  end date
```

script:-

Comment: `IFS=/ read VARSDD VARSMM VARSYY <<<"$STARTDATE"` is much more efficient than doing a separate `cut` pipeline for each.

Comment: (That said, all-caps variable names are used for variables meaningful to the shell and OS-provided tools; lower-case names are reserved for application use and are what you should be using for variables you make yourself -- see the relevant section of the POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that regular shell variables and environment variables share a single namespace).

Comment: Also, `expr` generally shouldn't be used in modern code -- it's an artifact of the 1970s; every shell compatible with the 1992 POSIX sh standard supports `VARSMM=$(( VARSMM + 1 )` instead.

Comment: Beyond that, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: (Also, note that use of `-a` in `[` is marked obsolescent; see the OB markers in [the POSIX specification for `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)).

Comment: ...and re: `for i in $(zgrep ...)` or its older backtick-based equivalent, see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i will make changes to script , https://www.shellcheck.net/ is really useful for checking the errors thanks again for url  ,   But what change i need to make to stop searching all the logs