# Search files between data range bash

Tags: bash, shell, postfix-mta

I have mail-log files created every day with ddmmyyyy.log.gz format, need to search  between from 30042020  to 03052020. or any date range (date range search comes to me from web-page) and i will process using other bash script ,how can i achieve this using bash script to select only specified files to bash array. log files

```
enter code here
maillog-29042020.log.gz
maillog-30042020.log.gz
maillog-01052020.log.gz
maillog-02052020.log.gz
maillog-02052020.log.gz
maillog-03052020.log.gz
maillog-04052020.log.gz
maillog-05052020.log.gz
maillog-06052020.log.gz
maillog-07052020.log.gz 
maillog-08052020.log.gz 
maillog-09052020.log.gz
```

example:- between from 30/04/2020  to 03/05/2020 
requested  output to  array

```
enter code here
 maillog-30042020.log.gz
 maillog-01052020.log.gz
 maillog-02052020.log.gz 
 maillog-03052020.log.gz
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share, what you have tried so far.

Comment: tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61839434/bash-end-loop-for-postfix-logs?noredirect=1#comment109377775_61839434

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
start_dt="20200430"
end_dt="20200503"
for file in maillog* ; 
do  
    f_dt=$(grep -o '[0-9]*' <<<${file});
    frtm_dt=${f_dt:4:4}${f_dt:2:2}${f_dt:0:2}; 
    if [[ "${frtm_dt}" -ge "${start_dt}" && "${frtm_dt}" -le "${end_dt}" ]]; then
        echo ${file}
    fi  
done
```

Demo :

```
$ls -1 maillog-* 
maillog-01052020.log.gz
maillog-02052020.log.gz
maillog-03052020.log.gz
maillog-04052020.log.gz
maillog-05052020.log.gz
maillog-06052020.log.gz
maillog-07052020.log.gz
maillog-08052020.log.gz
maillog-09052020.log.gz
maillog-29042020.log.gz
maillog-30042020.log.gz
$start_dt="20200430"
$end_dt="20200503"
$for file in maillog* ; 
> do  
>     f_dt=$(grep -o '[0-9]*' <<<${file});
>     frtm_dt=${f_dt:4:4}${f_dt:2:2}${f_dt:0:2}; 
>     if [[ "${frtm_dt}" -ge "${start_dt}" && "${frtm_dt}" -le "${end_dt}" ]]; then
>     echo ${file}
>     fi  
> done
maillog-01052020.log.gz
maillog-02052020.log.gz
maillog-03052020.log.gz
maillog-30042020.log.gz
$
```

Explanation: 
`start_dt="20200430"`
`end_dt="20200503"` <-- Initiate start and end date in "YYYYMMDD" format

`for file in maillog* ;`   <--  read file names

`f_dt=$(grep -o '[0-9]*' <<<${file});` <-- get Date part from the file name

`frtm_dt=${f_dt:4:4}${f_dt:2:2}${f_dt:0:2};` <-- Format date from file name in YYYYMMDD format

`if [[ "${frtm_dt}" -ge "${start_dt}" && "${frtm_dt}" -le "${end_dt}" ]];` --> Check if file name date is greater than or equal to start date and less tha equal to end date

Comment: Thanks for logic and explanation,  but if i change the from_dt  value  and end date_dt  this logic don't work ,